# change the default confirm button in bootbox and yii2

Tags: yii2, bootbox

I'm using bootbox.js along with yii2 framework to change the default confirmation popup on delete actions.
When I hit the "delete" buttons the bootbox popup appear properly but the "ok" button is preselected, so if the user hit the "enter" button the action take place.

Is it possible to change the default selected button from "ok" to "cancel"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything baked into the library to do what you want, but something like this should work:

```
var dialog = bootbox.confirm("Please confirm action", function(result){ 
    /* handle result */ 
});

dialog.on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
  dialog.find('.modal-footer .btn.btn-default').focus();
});
```